# Should private methods be placed above or below public methods?

Tags: java, methods, coding-style, refactoring, conventions

Are there any conventions as to whether private methods should generally be placed above or below public methods? E.g. say `caller()` was refactored into two methods - where would be the more standard place out of `aboveCaller()` or `belowCaller()`?

```
private void aboveCaller() { /*...here?...*/ }

public void caller() {
    aboveCaller();
    belowCaller();
}

private void belowCaller() { /*...or here?...*/ }
```

Although this is in Java, it is a general programming question and not really aimed at a specific language. (Apologies if it has been asked before - tried searching on here but didn't come up with anything).

Comment: Yes. But they're conventions and not universal truths. I would just group by access modifier, but some people prefer to define things before they are called.

Comment: I think this question is not fit in here. Since this question regarding code formating and there is no direct answer other than a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [top-down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design) design, I first write the methods calls, then implement them, so they'll be under.

Others prefer them to be above the caller since it's clearer (You first encounter the implementation, then see the call).

One thing for sure, follow your convention.

Comment: It seems the convention is usually "public before private" and this is also the default "Members Sort Order" in Eclipse (if "Sort members in same category by visibility" is ticked) so I'm going with this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a convention. However, I usually put belowCaller below. It's a supporting function of the main function and I don't want to look at it until I come across it in the main function's content. That being said, I put all public functions first, followed by all private functions. I put class variables at the top. Also, javadoc for each non obvious function will help a lot in understanding the code.

Answer (score 1):

20 people are going to answer this question, and you're going to end up with 25 different answers.

I don't think there's a standard convention, and in Java it doesn't matter. You could list them alphabetically, or group related methods together, or list private methods first and then public methods, or group setters first and then getters, or list getters and setters together in pairs, etc.

You should do whatever feels most natural to you, unless your professor or boss has defined another convention.

Edit: to see just how arbitrary it is, take a look at all the similar questions in the "related" bar to the right.

Comment: I'm looking for a convention as to what is most commonly done or expected - e.g. where would you look for such a method if you were scrolling through file of code in a text editor with no IDE tools? One theoretical way to answer this would be to get hold of all the code that has ever been written and count the number of methods that are above/below their callers - would be surprised if it were a 50/50 split!

Comment: I would *not* be surprised if it was a 50/50 split. I think you're more likely to find one of the (admittedly arbitrary) "conventions" I mentioned than you are to find an above/below convention.